# How to get In and out time from time column in python

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, python-2.7

I have a data in which I am trying to bring in and out time into columns from multiple rows eg:

```
date         Time         AVD_ID       device_NO d_No_id    ID          Check_In    Check_out   Route   Stop_name                    Amount
01/03/2019  5:06:00 PM  B1910_EVD_04    166450     23442 602803314916 :    1           0          22    Canada Water bus station       7.5
01/03/2019  5:38:00 PM  B1910_EVD_05    166451     23443 602803314916 :    0           1          22    Tottenham Court Road station   -4.5
```

now I want to create In_time, out_time on the basis of time and bring Amount, check_in and out in one row for eg:

Expected Output:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, this is what you need

```
df1 = df.drop(['AVD_ID','device_NO','d_No_id'],axis=1)
in_vals= df1.loc[df['Check_In']== 1].drop(['Check_out'],axis=1).rename(columns={'Time':'In_Time','Stop_name':'In_Stop_name','Amount':'In_Amount'})
out_vals= df1.loc[df['Check_out']== 1].drop(['Check_In'],axis=1).rename(columns={'Time':'Out_Time','Stop_name':'Out_Stop_name','Amount':'Out_Amount'})
new_df = pd.concat([in_vals.set_index(['date','ID','Route' ]), 
                out_vals.set_index(['date','ID','Route'])], 
                axis=1).reset_index()
new_df[['date','In_Time','Out_Time','ID','Check_In','Check_out','Route','In_Stop_name','Out_Stop_name','In_Amount','Out_Amount']]
```

**Output**
[image]